# jQuery: Join hidden table and insert column into another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So lets say I have html table A and html table B structured like below.

```
Table A (id="a")
ID#        Count
XX         XX
XX         XX
```

and

```
Table B (id="b") like this:
ID#        Desc.
XX         XX
XX         XX
```

Using jQuery, how can I join them and insert the count column from table A into B?  I don't want to create a new table, just insert part of table A into B to look like this:

```
Updated table B:
ID#        Count      Desc.
XX         XX         XX
XX         XX         XX
```

-Thanks!

UPDATE, Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/3VHEY/

Comment: I had those examples laid out like a table but the editor smashed it all together when I submitted the post...

Comment: Could you please include a demo fiddle?

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle for it:  http://jsfiddle.net/3VHEY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code

1. creates the "Count" column in table "B",
2. writes NULL into every cell of the new column,
3. for each row in table "A" finds the row in table "B" which has the same ID, and writes the count into these.

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/umX6G/4/).

```
$(function () {
    var $table_a_rows = $('#table_a tr'),
        $table_b_rows = $('#table_b tr');
    $table_b_rows.each(function (index) {
        $(this).find('td').eq(0).after('<td>' + (index === 0 ? 'Count' : 'NULL') +'</td>');
    });    
    $table_a_rows.each(function (index) {
        var $this_cells = $(this).find('td'),
            id = $this_cells.eq(0).text(),
            count = $this_cells.eq(1).text();
        if (index === 0) {
            return;
        }
        $table_b_rows.each(function () {
            var $this_cells = $(this).find('td');
            if ($this_cells.eq(0).text() === id) {
                $this_cells.eq(1).text(count);
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

Comment: Only thing is, now lets say the table has an unknown number of columns?

Comment: @metsales Which table?

Comment: actually truthfully we would need to know the layout of at least one of the tables, or know exactly where we want to put the column. I was really asking that question for the sake of completeness, but lets say that table a has the unknown number of columns

Comment: I had to create variants of some of the sub fuinctions to look for <th> elements, and it's working great.  Thank!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
 var rowsB = $('#table_b tr');
 var rowsA = $('#table_a tr');

 for(var i=0; i< rowsB.length ; i ++){
    var cells = $('td',$(rowsA[i])).clone();
    cells = cells.splice(1);
    $(rowsB[i]).append(cells);
 }

 var result = 0;

})
```